# Modifying a report to remove a record limit?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to modify a report that shows the Top 10 Customers by Sales. Currently, the report shows the top 10 customers, and stops.

I'm trying to remove the limit of 10, so I can see all customers sales data. I can't find where the report is setting this limit. I've looked through the formula editor, and can't find any relevant formulas to this limit.

Also there are no suppression formulas.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

Under the Report > Group Sort Expert menu, I was able to select between:

- No Sort
- All
- Top N
- Bottom N
- Top Percentage
- Bottom Percentage

for the group sort. I selected All, and now all my records are showing.